# how to get meetup access token on android, via oauth 2

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, meetup

my app needs to get user's meetup id.  meetup uses oauth 2.0.  found different pieces of code across the web, will paste in stackoverflow as answer to this question, for the next person.

Answer (score 3):

import a library via graddle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.smartam.leeloo:oauth2-common:0.1'
    compile 'net.smartam.leeloo:oauth2-client:0.1'
}
```

create a class for meetup authenticating.  this class written by adrianmaurer (https://gist.github.com/adrianmaurer/4673944), thank you adrianmaurer!

MeetupAuthActivity:

```
package pixtas.com.nightout;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

// leeloo oAuth lib https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0/wiki/Home
import net.smartam.leeloo.client.OAuthClient;
import net.smartam.leeloo.client.URLConnectionClient;
import net.smartam.leeloo.client.request.OAuthClientRequest;
import net.smartam.leeloo.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse;
import net.smartam.leeloo.client.response.OAuthAuthzResponse;
import net.smartam.leeloo.common.exception.OAuthProblemException;
import net.smartam.leeloo.common.exception.OAuthSystemException;
import net.smartam.leeloo.common.message.types.GrantType;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by tmr_byronMac on 4/24/15.
 */
public class MeetupAuthActivity  extends Activity {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    // Meetup OAuth Endpoints
    public static final String AUTH_URL = "https://secure.meetup.com/oauth2/authorize";
    public static final String TOKEN_URL = "https://secure.meetup.com/oauth2/access";

    //     Consumer
    //public static final String REDIRECT_URI_SCHEME = "oauthresponse";
    //public static final String REDIRECT_URI_HOST = "com.yourpackage.app";
    //public static final String REDIRECT_URI_HOST_APP = "yourapp";
    //public static final String REDIRECT_URI = REDIRECT_URI_SCHEME + "://" + REDIRECT_URI_HOST + "/";
    public static final String REDIRECT_URI = "NightOut://meetup.com";
    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "YOUR_KEY";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "YOUR_SECRET";

    private WebView _webview;
    private Intent _intent;
    private Context _context;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        _intent = getIntent();
        _context = getApplicationContext();

        _webview = new WebView(this);
        _webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        setContentView(_webview);

        _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        OAuthClientRequest request = null;
        try {
            request = OAuthClientRequest.authorizationLocation(
                    AUTH_URL).setClientId(
                    CONSUMER_KEY).setRedirectURI(
                    REDIRECT_URI).buildQueryMessage();
        } catch (OAuthSystemException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "OAuth request failed", e);
        }
        _webview.loadUrl(request.getLocationUri() + "&response_type=code&set_mobile=on");
    }

    public void finishActivity() {
        //do something here before finishing if needed
        finish();
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
            String error = uri.getQueryParameter("error");

            if (code != null) {
                new MeetupRetrieveAccessTokenTask().execute(uri);

                // setResult(RESULT_OK, _intent);
                // finishActivity();
            } else if (error != null) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, _intent);
                finishActivity();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class MeetupRetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri... params) {

            Uri uri = params[0];
            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");

            OAuthClientRequest request = null;

            try {
                request = OAuthClientRequest.tokenLocation(TOKEN_URL)
                        .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE).setClientId(
                                CONSUMER_KEY).setClientSecret(
                                CONSUMER_SECRET).setRedirectURI(
                                REDIRECT_URI).setCode(code)
                        .buildBodyMessage();

                OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());

                OAuthAccessTokenResponse response = oAuthClient.accessToken(request);

                // do something with these like add them to _intent
                // Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                // returnIntent.putExtra("access_token", response.getAccessToken());
                // setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);


                Log.d(TAG, "access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
                Log.d(TAG, response.getExpiresIn());
                Log.d(TAG, response.getRefreshToken());

                _intent.putExtra("access_token", response.getAccessToken());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, _intent);
                finish();
            } catch (OAuthSystemException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth System Exception - Couldn't get access token: " + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(_context, "OAuth System Exception - Couldn't get access token: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (OAuthProblemException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth Problem Exception - Couldn't get access token");
                Toast.makeText(_context, "OAuth Problem Exception - Couldn't get access token", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, _intent);
        finishActivity();
    }
}
```

call MeetupAuthActivity from  your main activity.
MainActivity:

```
public void getMeetupAccessToken(){
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, MeetupAuthActivity.class);
    // startActivity(intent);
    startActivityForResult(intent,GET_MEETUP_ACCESS_TOKEN_ACTIVITY);
}
```

in MainActivity, capture the results form auth activity.
MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        if(requestCode == GET_MEETUP_ACCESS_TOKEN_ACTIVITY)
        {
            accessToken = data.getExtras().getString("access_token");
            saveMeetupAccessTokenToSharedPreferences();

            //save meetupid plus device id to parse
            getMyMeetupIdFromMeetupServer();

            // Log.i(DEBUG_TAG,"MainActivity, accessToken" + accessToken);
        }
    }
```